# Uso de GIFs animados para ilustrar uma pergunta ou resposta

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas, formatação, imagem

Dois exemplos de uso:

- Pergunta: [Como colocar transição em um dropdown de um menu?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28963/como-colocar-transi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-dropdown-de-um-menu)
- Resposta: [Problemas em conteudo sobre demanda (infinite scroll)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31688/problemas-em-conteudo-sobre-demanda-infinite-scroll/31698#31698)

Podemos usar GIFs animados no site? Se sim, quais restrições e quais recomendações de uso? Se não, como proceder quando encontrarmos um post que usa?

Answer (score 11):

Acho que **sim** desde que se considere:

## *Necessidade*

No caso da pergunta, [fui eu quem postou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/28963/8) o GIF. E como explico no sumário da edição, ao se tratar de um efeito visual específico num site alheio, se o site for atualizado ou sair do ar, não tem como saber que efeito se está perguntando. No caso da resposta, mesmo que não seja necessário, me parece um bonus de uma resposta bem completa e tem quase zero impacto no quesito ***Peso*** .

## *Peso*

Visualmente, não pode ser estressante nem desviar muito a atenção. E também o tamanho do arquivo não deve ir muito além dos 200kb <sup>*(lembre que um moderador pode estar tentando [moderar o site através do celular](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/uso-de-gifs-animados-para-ilustrar-uma-pergunta-ou-resposta/1940#comment5908_1940):)*</sup>.
O que tentei foi usar a menor quantidade possível de frames, com uma velocidade suave (1/100), com poucas cores (16) e a menor dimensão possível. O [GIF ficou com 123KB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7d5K.gif).

<sub>*Ferramenta recomendada (Win/OSX): [**LICEcap**](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) (já grava em gif).*</sub>

Comment: Uma resposta a favor do **não** pode favorecer publicar simplesmente o link para imagem arquivada no Stack.Imgur, mas deixo só como sugestão se alguém quiser fazer essa defesa.

Comment: 500k eu já acho muito. Abro muito o site no celular, e uma imagem com esse peso me daria uma certa raiva.

Comment: 500k, quem falou em 500k? :)

Comment: Ninguém não... ;)